# stl vector::insert difference in Windows and linux?

Tags: c++, list, stl, g++, compiler-errors

there. I've searched my question around here but failed to find anything relevant.
This is the problem.
I have this code in the part of my program, doing kind of stupid sort by inserts.
I developed that in MSVS 2008 and it all worked fine, but when I tried to compile that with g++, it failed because of `list::insert` function below;

```
//...
pair<uint, double> NewElem(i, Prob.at(i));
bool inserted(false);
vector<pair<uint, double> >::const_iterator li = NewList.begin();
for ( vector<double>::const_iterator ji = BlocksMemory.begin() ; ji != BlocksMemory.end() ; ++ji)
{
    if (NewElem.second <= *ji)
        li += _SORT_BLOCK;
    else
        break;
}
for(;li != NewList.end() ; ++li)
{
    if (NewElem.second > li->second)
    {
        NewList.insert(li, NewElem );
        inserted = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

as one can see, `li` is `const_iterator` of `NewList`;
And `NewElem` has type `pair` with the same content type as `NewList` contents;

There you can see the response (unreadable):

> main.cpp:447: error: no matching function for call to "`std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, double>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, double> > >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::pair<unsigned int, double>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, double>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, double> > > >&, std::pair<unsigned int, double>&)`"
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc:106: note: candidates are: `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> > std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::pair<unsigned int, double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, double> >]`
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:850: note:                 `void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, size_t, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::pair<unsigned int, double>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, double> >]`

**What can be the reason? And what is the possible solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the `insert` member function that you are trying to use is probably:

```
iterator insert( iterator, const value_type& );
```

But the first argument that you are passing to the function is a `const_iterator`, that cannot be implicitly converted to a non const `iterator`. That code should not have worked on VS either.

The simple solution is that if you intend to modify the container you use a non-const `iterator`: define `li` as `std::vector< std::pair<uint,double> >::iterator li = NewList.begin();`

Comment: Yes, thanks... I'll be damned, it looks like I was very tired while writing this part of code :) That's was kinda automative, I'm usually passing arguments on `const &`, so in case of vector it could not be iterated with simple `vector::iterator`. In my case I had defined vector in the local scope there there were no need to use     `const_iterator`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Also, are you sure that you want to be inserting into a std::vector?  For performance reasons, a std::list would be a better choice.  Also, an insert on a list doesn't invalidate existing iterators as it does for a vector.

Comment: Yes, you're right, also there'll be no need to use sequential memory block in case of large amount of data. I'll revise the code.